# silverlight MVVM A view within a view

Tags: mvvm

I'm working on a little workout application and am running into an issue of displaying a view within another view.

I have a `WorkoutSummaryView` with a backing `WorkoutSummaryViewModel`. Within the workout summary view, I want to display the list of `SingleExerciseView` items. Each `SingleExerciseView` has a backing `SingleExerciseViewModel` which displays the name and exercise and an `ObservableCollection<Set>` ie Sets of exercises with a weight/reps pair.

**Simplified Code:**

```
public class ExerciseSummaryViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ExerciseSummaryViewModel()
    {
       _workout = DB.GetWorkout();

        foreach (Exercise ex in _workout.Exercises)
            ExerciseVMs.Add(new SingleExerciseViewModel(ex));

    }
    public ObservableCollection<SingleExerciseViewModel> ExerciseVms { get; private set; }
}

 //Code for singleExerciseVM

public class SingleExerciseViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public SingleExerciseViewModel(Exercise exercise)
    {
        Name = exercise.Name;
        Sets = exercise.Sets;                        
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Set> Sets { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is I'm not sure how to go from here to get my SingleExerciseViewModels to display. I did try setting the dataContext for the SingleExerciseView in xaml to my SEVM, but that's still not working.

```
//XAML for ExerciseSummaryView
<ListBox Height="496" Width="412" ItemsSource="{Binding ExerciseVms}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <local:SingleExerciseView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                                                         
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're aggregating the SingleExerciseViewModels into a collection - but they are not attached to their views! That isn't going to work.

Each SingleExerciseViewModel needs to be attached to a SingleExerciseView. Then, each one of those views needs to be bound to a control on the ExerciseSummaryView that will display them (a ListView for example, because it can show custom user controls).